# Create a Boolean column for unique rows in a grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a grouped data frame `df_grouped`, I would like to create a new boolean column `df_grouped["Unique"]` where for each subset of grouping, this column is `True` if the values of `location` is unique within the grouping & `False` if it's not unique.

```
dataset = {
    'ID': ['One', 'One', 'One', 'Five', 'Five','Five','Four'],
    'Day': [2, 2, 2, 1, 1,1,0],
    'Location': ['London', 'London', 'Paris', 'London', 'Paris','Paris','Berlin']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Name','Day'])
```

Expected output for the unique column:

```
'Unique': [False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` and inverted mask by `~`:

```
df['Unique'] = ~df.duplicated(['ID','Day', 'Location'], keep=False)
print (df)
     ID  Day Location  Unique
0   One    2   London   False
1   One    2   London   False
2   One    2    Paris    True
3  Five    1   London    True
4  Five    1    Paris   False
5  Five    1    Paris   False
6  Four    0   Berlin    True
```